# Listing specific values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table here named, `TEST`. I want to display the number of left-handed and right-handed persons of my family.

How would one do so? Here is what I did:

```
+---------+---------+
|  NAME   |  HANDED |
+---------+---------+
| Jeffrey |    R    |
| Ashley  |    L    |
|  Bob    |    R    |
|  Dad    |    R    |
|  Mom    |    R    |
+---------+---------+

SELECT HANDED, COUNT(HANDED) AS COUNT_HANDED
FROM TEST
WHERE HANDED = 'L' OR HANDED = 'R';
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
+---------+--------------+
|  HANDED | COUNT_HANDED |
+---------+--------------+
|    L    |       1      |
|    R    |       4      |
+---------+--------------+
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Just add `group by handed` to the end...

Comment: Oh! I am so dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple!

```
SELECT HANDED, COUNT(HANDED)
AS COUNT_HANDED
FROM TEST
GROUP BY HANDED;
```